# Cannot reach Ingress in Kubernetes when running Minikube on Mac M1

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress, apple-m1

I am trying to run a local cluster on Mac with M1 chip using Minikube (Docker driver). I enabled ingress addon in Minikube, I have a separate terminal in which I'm running `minikube tunnel` and I enabled Minikube dashboard, which I want to expose using Ingress.
This is my configuration file:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dashboard.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: kubernetes-dashboard
                port:
                  number: 80
            pathType: Prefix
            path: /
```

I also put "dashboard.com" in my /etc/hosts file and it's actually resolving to the right IP, but it's not responding when I put "http://dashboard.com" in a browser or when I try to ping it and I always receive a timeout.

NOTE: when I run `minikube tunnel` I get

```
❗  The service/ingress dashboard-ingress requires privileged ports to be exposed: [80 443]
  sudo permission will be asked for it.
```

I insert my sudo password and then nothing gets printed afterwards. Not sure if this is is an issue or the expected behavior.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to expose the ingress on a different port?  Usually [TCP Ports 1-1023](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) are protected in a way that makes permissions an issue.  If you can reach it through a different port (e.g. 3000), it's a permissions issue.  If you can't reach it through a non-privileged port, its probably a different issue entirely.

Comment: I tried to edit my Ingress and expose a different port, nothing changes... Nothing happens on the ingress controller pod logs, I guess that requests are not arriving to the cluster but I don't understand why

Answer (score 3):

I had the same behavior, and apparently what's needed for `minikube tunnel` to work is to map "127.0.0.1" in `/etc/hosts`, instead of the output from `minikube ip` or the ingress description.
that fixed it for me

Comment: map to what exactly ?

Comment: it's been a while but i believe i meant to say map it to the ingress hosts, so in your `/etc/hosts/` you might want something like: `127.0.0.1 hello-world.info`

Comment: sadly that doesn't seem to work on my mac m1. By any chance, can you share a minimal yaml file with ingress, clusterIP and a pod that works on your machine ?

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue on mac *m1*, initialy tried addon ingress-dns but then realised while it can be enabled its not currently working or supported using the docker driver https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332#issuecomment-608133325

some other mac *intel* users have got it working using hyperkit driver but thats not available for mac *m1* yet

my answer for now is to use minikube tunnel https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/ and add entry to /etc/hosts for ingress, also have to pass in the cluster name using the -p parameter eg: minikube tunnel --cleanup -p <CLUSTER_NAME>